# Overwritten block not used

Tags: blocks, overrides

I have a block that I have overwritten but it doesn't seem to work. I saw a guide on the web and it didn't seem that difficult, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

It's just using default - here is some code :o)

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Bundle>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Bundle>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <product>
                    <view>
                        <type>
                            <bundle>
                                <rewrite>
                                    <option>Namespace_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option</option>
                                </rewrite>
                            </bundle>
                        </type>
                    </view>
                </product>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**I've created the class**

```
class Namespace_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option{

    public function getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection, $includeContainer = true){

        return 'TEST';

    }

}
```

**Namespace_Bundle.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Bundle>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_Bundle>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I've checked to see that the module is active and it is.

**UPDATE**

Altered the config.xml to:

```
<rewrite>
    <product_view_type_bundle_option>Namespace_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option</product_view_type_bundle_option>
</rewrite>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Altered the module name to MyBundle instead - still no difference

**UPDATE 3**

Was not calling the right module / file

Answer (score 1):

It's not the right way of overriding a block, your config.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Bundle>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Bundle>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_bundle_option>Namespace_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option</product_view_type_bundle_option>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: To complete @Digital Pianism answer you can find a tutorial how to override Core files by Inchoo : http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: That means you've probably another module rewriting the same block. Disable all non Magento modules and try again.

Comment: I have now disabled all module except Mage_ and it is still not working.

Comment: Try naming your module with a non Magento module name: e.g. Mybundle instead of Bundle. Are your modules files sitting under app/code/local ?

Comment: Yes, they are in app/code/local and I my module is now named MyBundle no difference.

Comment: And if you add return 'TEST'; in the original Magento block does it work ? If it doesn't that means you're either not rewriting the block you want to or you are not visiting a page using this block.

Comment: You're right it is the wrong block. Thank you for your help. I'll try to track down the block :o)